# Using the risk neutral version of the First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing to derive a partial differential equation

Tags: black-scholes, finance, asset-pricing, differential-equations

I have to use the risk neutral version of the First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing to
derive a partial differential equation (PDE) that the price/value process, $V_t = F(t,S_t)$,
of a self-financing Markovian portfolio has to satisfy.

Some context:

Let $W$ be a standard Browian motion. We are in a financial market consisting of a risky asset $S$ and a money-market account $B$ with:

$$dS_t = a(b - S_t)dt + \sigma S_tdW_t$$
$$dB_t = rB_tdt$$

where,
$$B_0 = 1,\; S_0 = s_0, \;\sigma > 0 \; \text{and}\; a,b \; \text{are constants unequal to zero.}$$

Normally, we don't have to use the FFT and we use these two equations:
$$V_t = \phi_tS_t + \psi_tB_t$$
$$dV_t = \phi_tdS_t + \psi_tdB_t $$

I know that the FFTAP tells us that under regularity conditions absence of arbitrage holds if and only if, for some numeraire $N$, there exists a probability measure $\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}_N$ such that:

1. $\mathbb{Q} \sim \mathbb{P}$
2. For any asset $A$ in the market, the discounted price process $A/N$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-martingale, i.e.
   $$\frac{A_t}{N_t} = \mathbb{E_Q}\left[ \frac{A_T}{N_T} | \mathcal{F}_t \right]$$

Could someone help me get started, since I have no idea how to start. If I need to provide extra information let me know and I will try to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the answer to a [related question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69064/risk-neutral-pricing-to-determine-no-arbitrage-price) of yours it was shown that under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q$ the process
$$
S_te^{-rt}=S_0e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2}+\sigma W^{\mathbb Q}_t}
$$
is a martingale. In other words, under the risk-neutral $\mathbb Q\,,$ the numeraire $N_t$ is the money market account $e^{rt}\,.$ From
\begin{align}
V_t=F(t,S_t)=e^{-(T-t)r}\mathbb E\big[F(T,S_T)\big|S_t\big]\,
\end{align}
it follows directly that $F(t,S_t)e^{-rt}$ is a martingale as well.
Applying Ito's formula yields
\begin{align}
&e^{-rT}F(T,S_T)\\&
\quad=F(0,S_0)+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_TF(t,S_t)\,dt+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_xF(t,S_t)\,dS_t\\&\quad\quad+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_x^2F(t,S_t)\,d\langle S\rangle_t\\
&\quad\quad-r\int_0^Te^{-rt}F(t,S_t)\,dt \\
&\quad=F(0,S_0)+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_TF(t,S_t)\,dt+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_xF(t,S_t)\,r\,S_t\,dt\\&\quad\quad+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_xF(t,S_t)\,\sigma\,S_t\,dW^{\mathbb Q}_t\\&\quad\quad+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_x^2F(t,S_t)\,\sigma^2 S_t^2\,dt-r\int_0^Te^{-rt}F(t,S_t)\,dt\,.
\end{align}
From the martingale property we know that $F(0,S_0)=\mathbb E[e^{-rT}F(T,S_T)]$ holds. It follows that
\begin{align}
0&=\mathbb E\Bigg[\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_TF(t,S_t)\,dt+\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_xF(t,S_t)\,r\,S_t\,dt\\&\quad+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Te^{-rt}\partial_x^2F(t,S_t)\,\sigma^2 S_t^2\,dt-r\int_0^Te^{-rt}F(t,S_t)\,dt \Bigg]\,.
\end{align}
Consequently, the Black-Scholes PDE
\begin{align}
0=\partial_TF(t,S_t)+\partial_xF(t,S_t)\,r\,S_t+\frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2F(t,S_t)\,\sigma^2 S_t^2-rF(t,S_t)\,
\end{align}
holds.

Comment: Thanks @Kurt G.