# Black and Scholes PDE in terms of Future Price

Tags: black-scholes, forward, pde

I was trying to understand why the Black and Scholes PDE for the value of an option, $V (F , t)$, with the forward price, $F$, as underlying is

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2F^2\frac{\partial ^2V}{\partial F^2} - rV = 0$$

Why does the delta term vanish?

Comment: Since a futures price is not a forward price you should probably fix the title of the question. I assume the question is about the forward price for maturity $T$ which is $F_t=e^{r(T-t)}S_t=S_0\,e^{rT+\sigma W_t-\sigma^2t/2}=F_0\,e^{\sigma W_t-\sigma^2t/2}\,.$ Therefore, $dF_t=\sigma F_t\,dW_t\,.$ If you use that instead of $dS_t=rS_t\,dt+\sigma S_t\,dW_t$ in [my favourite derivation of the BS PDE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/69087/58786) you will see that there is no delta term.

Comment: What you call "the delta term" is the term $+ r S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$. This term is related to the financing (at the rate $r$) of the hedging position in the stock, when you hedge with futures you do not have such a cost (futures do not require a cash investment) and therefore the term is absent. This is the financial,  as opposed to the *mathematical* explanation that Kurt G. gave.